# How to Delete records on database end with flag or without?

Tags: mysql, angular, database

I've a customer table **Hobbies** where we store his/her hobbies.

Say if a customer with **`id=123`** has 10 hobbies with delete button next to each. when delete is clicked i'll remove the row from UI(using Angular - not sent to server yet). on **Save** i'll pass the data to server .

> Scenario : I'll delete 5 records from UI & click on save.

**Approach 1:**

I'll pass 5 records to server & i'll remove everything on table with `id=123` and insert the passed 5 records.

**Approach 2:**

I'll pass 10 records but with a flag '**false**' for deleted 5 records & i'll remove them on db end by checking flag.

I just don't want to follow some approach blindly without knowing it's drawbacks.

In application architecture standpoint can someone share there valuable views.

Comment: Well approach 2 is recoverable (and maintains database integrity). Approach 1 isn't (and might not). Take your pick, but personally, I don't think end users should be allowed to execute DELETE statements against a database - unless there's a legal obligation to allow them to do so.

Comment: @Strawberry valid but even tough i pass flag i'm deleting it based on it one way or other both achieves same.

Comment: No. Option 2 makes it invisible. That's not the same as deleting it.

Comment: @Strawberry by doing so maybe i need deal with these 1) with the flag i see writing lot more code than required on front end, every time i need to set that flag & hide it based on UI. 2) even my request header will be large. appreciate your view mate.

Comment: I do not like the idea to delete records first and then re-add them with the same value. If you have triggers on the table (that log something for example) or replication it would be a mess. So I'm usually using approach 3: DELETE FROM table WHERE id = 123 AND value NOT IN (list from UI)